# JUnit Testing: invoking parent class protected method

Tags: java, reflection, methods, junit, protected

Here is my class hierarchy

```
abstract Class A
{
   int i = 0;
   protected init (String param1, String param2)
   {
       //do lots of common things based on param1, param2 and save data in i
   } 
}
```

Then there are 3-4 classes which implements A i.e

```
Class B extends A
{
    public B ()
    {
        super ();
    }

    public void performSomeAction ()
    {
        init (param1_specific_to_class_B, param2_specific_to_class_B); //calling parent class method 
        //do rest of teh random things
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to write a JUnit test for class A. Basically I want to test whatever `init` method is doing is accurate or not. I tried this

```
Class clas = A.class;
B b = new B();

Method A_init;
A_init = clas.getDeclaredMethod("init", String.class, String.class);
A_init.invoke(b, param1_specific_to_class_B, param2_specific_to_class_B);
```

But its not working and i am getting following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class test.package.subpackage.ATest can not access a member of class package.subpackage.A with modifiers "protected"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at test.package.subpackage.ATest.initTest(ATest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place your test class in the same package as the class being tested. So the test class  will have access to the protected method.

Another option, a bit more elegant, is make the protected method accessible:

```
A_init = clas.getDeclaredMethod("init", String.class, String.class);
A_init.setAccessible(true);
A_init.invoke(b, param1_specific_to_class_B, param2_specific_to_class_B);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: moving the class to that package isn't an option since we have 2 different package heirarchy (project classes being in src folder and test being in test foldeR). thanks for the `setAccessible(true)`. Thats what i was looking for

Comment: As happens with Maven projects, you have an src and a test folder, but different folders not necessarily mean different packages.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` members of a class are not [visible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to a class from another package unless it's a subclass of the former.

However in your application the class `test.package.subpackage.ATest` is trying to access a protected method from another class in `package.subpackage`, which results in the access violation.

Try placing the `ATest` class to a location such that both `A` and `ATest` belong to the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively in your TestClass create a Subclass of A and expose the protected method(s) through a public method:

```
public class TestClass extends TestCase(){

   // ...

   private class AChild extends A{
      public exposeInit (String param1, String param2){
         super.init(param1, param2);
      }
   }
}
```

now you can test init of class A by testing init of class AChild.

I had similar problem, but we solved it by changing design to composition instead of inheritence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but, since B is not overriding A.init()   (at least, from what I can see) you could just go

```
B b = new B()
b.init(param1_specific_to_class_B, param2_specific_to_class_B)
```

If B is overriding init(),

1. put everything in the same package (as others have posted)
2. if changing packages is not possible or desired, you may have to add a special method to B that calls `super.init()`.  I'd name it something like `callSuperInitForUnitTests()` and make it clear in the comments that this is a workaround for unit testing.

Comment: I knew that B was extending A.  The point is that if you want to test A.init, and B is not overriding A.init, you can just call b.init().  Otherwise, these are a few possible workarounds: move the files to the same package, set accessible, or call A.init via an intermediate.